# @GetMapping return string info that list is empty

Tags: java, rest, controller, response

Sometimes there may happen, that in database is nothing, method .findAll() has nothing to show and returns empty body. I know I have return type of this function "List" and I can not directly return string, but how could I send respond body as string or JSON, if list is empty, to let user know? I want to give receiver information that database is empty so it is clear for him.

Class annotations are

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")
```

Code example:

```
@GetMapping
public Iterable<User> findAll() {
    List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
    if(userList.isEmpty()){
        // return "This list is empty :(";
    }
    return userList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less something you might do on the front-end. However, what you could return is a POJO that contains the List and a String representing a message about the List, if necessary.

```java
class UserFindAllResponse {

    private final List<User> users;

    private final String message;

    // constructor, getters

}
```

```java
@GetMapping
public UserFindAllResponse findAll() {
    List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();

    return new UserFindAllResponse(userList, userList.isEmpty() ? "There appears to be no users" : "There are x users");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller layer, you should return a **response mapping** with the returned list from the database. Therefore, if it is empty, the value on the front-end will be zero.

So if the length of the `userList` is empty, we know the DB is empty and you can show a message to the user.

#### Example front-end Pseudo-code

```js
fetch("${url}/users").then(response => {
    if (response.data.length == 0) {
        # Show message here, choose whichever way you want
        alert("Oh no! Database table was empty")
    }
    else {
        setData(response.data);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could choose to throw an error from the back-end and then resolve the error on the front-end and again show a message to the user about the empty DB.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Although this solution is based on front-end, it is very helpful answer. Many thanks!
BTW that line "Oh no!" got me :)